How to Generate PGP Key in Azure Cloud Shell
Up until recently (a couple months ago) I was able to generate PGP keys using Azure Cloud Shell like such:
gpg --homedir=$homedir --batch --gen-key pgp-params.txt

Recently, when I try it, I get an error.
gpg: error running '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2
gpg: failed to start gpg-agent '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': General error
gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: General error
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
gpg: key generation failed: No agent running

I have changed nothing. I log in as the same user. I use the same PS1 scripts. Perhaps the Azure Cloud Shell image has changed?
Bottom line, how can I accomplish this now?
As a side note, afterwards, I ran
gpg-agent --daemon

which resulted in
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

UPDATE
This problem goes away if I do not use the --homedir option. I tried setting GNUPGHOME (thinking the problem might be related to this old issue: here) but that did not resolve the issue--I had the same error(s).
So, I still need to be able to generate a PGP key using 'batch' mode and using a specified home directory, rather than the default home directory.

Are you still facing the issue? @Donny Kwitty

As you mentioned, it seems like the issue is with the cloud shell environment changes only. An alternative approach for this is using a temporary directory instead of using home directory to generate the key and then copy from temp directory to home directory later.
tempdiry=$(mktemp -d)

gpg --batch --gen-key <filename> --output "$tempdiry/"

Once it is generated, use cp command by providing file path and destination file path as detailed in this document.
Note: Also try exploring alternatives such as gpg2 or gnupg, depending on what is available in Azure Cloud Shell and suitable for your environment.

Yes--I can certainly do something like this. However, I do not want the newly generated key to be stored in the keyring, etc. I want to be able to generate a new PGP key and then be able to delete the temporary directory--removing the keyring, etc. In the Azure cloud shell, I do not have permissions to delete keys that I generate. Very strange!

Are you holding an admin role? @DonnyKwitty

There is no root access in Azure Cloud Shell.
